# Make unit test executable only

Tags: cmake

I am very new to cmake which my current project make uses off. The issue I am facing is that while making complete build I am facing issues but my requirement is to make unittest component only.

I do see the unittest source directory and below are the file in it:

```
cmake_install.cmake
CTestTestfile.cmake
```

How can I separately compile the unittest directory only?

Comment: Wouldn't the unit test require the libraries or executables of the main project? If that's the case, I don't think there is any value in building them separately unless they are separate projects. It is much more typical to have an option to disable building tests, but not generally the other way around. Perhaps more information is required to fully understand your setup.

Comment: I fully agree with you but is there a command to dump what cmake is processing - which build which script etc ?

Comment: @Prakash `cmake --trace` or `cmake --trace-expand`.

Comment: When I run cmake --build . I get a compilation error stating a file Not found in a specific directory - but when I add --trace / --trace-expand to the cmake command : cmake --trace-expand --build . I do not see the same compilation error rather the command ends with "Build files have been written to .." at console - why I am not able to see the compilation error now though the unittest executable is also not generated which would mean the build failed?

Comment: `cmake --build` runs the build using the build system for which you generated the build files during `cmake <dir>`. For example, if you have generated the makefiles, `cmake --build` will run `make`. If you generated Xcode project, `cmake --build` will run `xcodebuild`. `--trace` only shows progress of `cmake <dir>`, not `cmake --build`.